# How to get arrowheads at both ends of arc path element?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am using d3.svg.arc() to draw a segment of a circle setting the inner and outer radii to be the same and with some random sweeping angle. And now I want to get arrow heads on both ends of it. The marker-start property is working fine. But the problem is with marker-end. When I am running the code, I am getting both the markers at the start itself. Please help me out.

```
<svg version="1.1">
<defs>
    <marker id="endtriangle"
  viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" 
  markerUnits="strokeWidth"
  markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
  orient="auto">
    <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" />
    </marker>
    <marker id="starttriangle"
  viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" 
  markerUnits="strokeWidth"
  markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3"
  orient="auto">
    <path d="M -2 5 L 8 0 L 8 10 z" />
    </marker>
</defs>
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
var arc=d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(140)
    .outerRadius(140)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(Math.PI/3)
d3.select("svg").append("path")
        .attr("d",arc)
        .attr("transform","translate(200,200)")
        .attr("stroke","black")
        .attr("marker-end","url(#endtriangle)")
        .attr("marker-start","url(#starttriangle)")
        .attr("fill","none")
        .attr("stroke-width","10")
        .attr("id","dimen")
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant portion of your svg file?

Comment: updated the question with code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be because D3 generates an arc path that isn't directly suited for this use-case.

Here's an example that I got from removing about half of the generated arc path data (the `d` attribute): http://jsfiddle.net/MQNXZ/

The top path is using your example, the bottom one a cleaned up static version. The difference compared to the D3 path data is that the D3 variant includes an additional straight line command, several arc commands and a close path command.

Comment: Thanks man. But how did you get the path coordinates?? Also, what if we want to draw more than one arc segments. We can't obviously calculate and change the path of every other segment.

Comment: Obtained from inspecting/copying the d3.arc output, anyway, if you want to generate an arc path closer to my static output, just add something similar to the built-in d3.arc object, https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/arc.js. Cut away about half of the arc path generator code there, to match the static version in my fiddle.

Comment: I am new to coding. Can you please update the code in jsfiddle??Thanks!!

Comment: I tried cutting the code in arc path but in vain. Don't know where I am going wrong.

Comment: As Erik says, the d3 arc command produces a solid shape like a curved rectangle (for want of a better description).  If you want your markers to work properly, you need to learn how the `<path>` A/a commands work.  Then add them to the path definition yourself.

Comment: Yeah i gave up on using the arc command. I calculated the path for every segment and drew the arcs. It works fine now. Thnx anyway!!